# How to call method from another Razor page?

Tags: asp.net-core

This is [structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ansun.png) of my App and i want to call a method in Login.cshtml from ExternalLogins.cshtml.cs class. How can I do that? Some asp helpers?

Login just like ExternalLogins is RazorPage - no controller class.

Edit:
@mj1313 I added this code:

```
<div class="col">
    <h3>Zaloguj się przez:</h3>
    @{
        if (Model.ExternalLogins.Count == 0)
        {
            <div>Brak możliwości zalogowania przez serwisy zewnętrzne.</div>
        }
        else
        {
            <form method="post" 
                  asp-page="./Manage/ExternalLogins" 
                  asp-page-handler="LinkLogin" 
                  asp-route-returnUrl="@Model.ReturnUrl">
                  <div>
                      @foreach (var provider in @Model.ExternalLogins)
                      {
                          <button type="submit" 
                                  class="btn btn-primary" 
                                  name="provider" 
                                  value="@provider.Name" 
                                  title="Zaloguj się za pomocą konta 
                                  @provider.DisplayName">
                              @provider.DisplayName
                          </button>
                      }
                  </div>
            </form>
        }
    }
</div>
```

But my Action in ExternalLogins not called

```
        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostLinkLoginAsync(string provider)
{
    // Clear the existing external cookie to ensure a clean login process
    await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme);

    // Request a redirect to the external login provider to link a login for the current user
    var redirectUrl = Url.Page("./ExternalLogins", pageHandler: "LinkLoginCallback");
    var properties = _signInManager.ConfigureExternalAuthenticationProperties(provider, redirectUrl, _userManager.GetUserId(User));
    return new ChallengeResult(provider, properties);
}
```

Comment: How about using [asp-page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/anchor-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-3.1#asp-page)? If it doesn't work, you can show us some codes.

Comment: @mj1313 when i debug my code it was something wrong because Login.cshmtl was executed, but ExternalLogins class (method LinkLogin) - no. Probably asp-page is not working right.

Comment: Seems you are using identity, `OnPostLinkLoginAsync` is used for  external services logging in, are you logging via something like facebook or google?

Comment: @mj1313 Yes, i use google and facebook, I have got simply form to login by my app, and I have got 2 buttons (Google and Facebook) to login from external services - side by side. 

I don't understand why Identity schema has default function external services logging in only after login my account. In manage my account... That doesn't make sense for me. I want login used my GoogleAccount.